# Finding matches between images with OpenCV dense SIFT

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, feature-detection, sift

I've implemented a dense feature detector using OpenCV following one of the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146570/opencv-python-dense-sift).

```
sift = cv2.SIFT()
dense=cv2.FeatureDetector_create("Dense")
kp1=dense.detect(template_detect)
des1=sift.compute(template_detect,kp1)
kp2=dense.detect(image_detect)
des2=sift.compute(image_detect,kp2)
```

It works well, however, I'm interested in comparing these two images to try and find matches between them. However when try to implement it like below I get the error "TypeError: queryDescriptors is not a numerical tuple".

```
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(template_detect,kp1,image_detect,kp2,matches[:4], 2, None)
```

Is there a better way I should be trying to implement key point matches between the images?

Answer (score 1):

You might have dropped this by now, but the error is that the [signature for compute()](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html) is

`Python: cv2.SIFT.compute(image, keypoints[, descriptors]) → keypoints, descriptors`

Your code assigns des1/des2 with a tuple of both the keypoints and the descriptors, which is not what you want. Correction to your code would be;

```
sift = cv2.SIFT()
dense=cv2.FeatureDetector_create("Dense")
kp1=dense.detect(template_detect)
_, des1=sift.compute(template_detect,kp1)
kp2=dense.detect(image_detect)
_, des2=sift.compute(image_detect,kp2)
```

This would drop the keypoints from the return.