# OpenCV-Python Dense SIFT Settings

Tags: python, opencv, sift, vlfeat

This is a follow-up question to the previously posted question about using OpenCVs dense sift implementation in python ([OpenCV-Python dense SIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146570/opencv-python-dense-sift/22368921#22368921)).

Using the suggested code for a dense sift

```
    dense=cv2.FeatureDetector_create("Dense")
    kp=dense.detect(imgGray)
    kp,des=sift.compute(imgGray,kp)
```

I have the following questions:

- Can I access any of the DenseFeatureDetector properties in python? Set or at least read?
- What is the logic behind c++s FeatureDetector::create becoming pythons FeatureDetector_create? How can I know that based on the documentation (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html)?
- Any recommendation on a python wrapper for VLFeat Library? Is pyvlfeat  still the way to go (I tried to setup pyvlfeat but it didn't compile on my mac)?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you can just query the builtin docs: `dense=cv2.FeatureDetector_create("Dense"); help(dense)` also be aware, that the interfaces for opencv3.0 have changed dramatically here, and won't allow you to use dense anymore, so careful.

Comment: I see; there will be no dense sift at all anymore or only not for python?

Comment: no, in general. but if you think of it, you can easily create your own keypoints

Answer (score 3):

You can see current (default) options with the following:

```
dense = cv2.FeatureDetector_create('Dense')
f = '{} ({}): {}'
for param in dense.getParams():
    type_ = dense.paramType(param)
    if type_ == cv2.PARAM_BOOLEAN:
        print f.format(param, 'boolean', dense.getBool(param))
    elif type_ == cv2.PARAM_INT:
        print f.format(param, 'int', dense.getInt(param))
    elif type_ == cv2.PARAM_REAL:
        print f.format(param, 'real', dense.getDouble(param))
    else:
        print param
```

Then you'd get an output like the following:

```
featureScaleLevels (int): 1
featureScaleMul (real): 0.10000000149
initFeatureScale (real): 1.0
initImgBound (int): 0
initXyStep (int): 6
varyImgBoundWithScale (boolean): False
varyXyStepWithScale (boolean): True
```

You can alter the options as the following:

```
dense.setDouble('initFeatureScale', 10)
dense.setInt('initXyStep', 3)
```