# Compute Dense SIFT features in OpenCV 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-science, sift

Since version 3.0, DenseFeatureDetector is no longer available. Could anybody please show me how to compute Dense SIFT features in OpenCV 3.0? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You mean something like DAISY features? It's in opencv 3.0 but in external contrib package. You have to compile it yourself

Comment: @DawidPi: I have opencv_contrib installed and included xfeature2d into the project, but still couldn't find anything like DenseFeatureDetector. Dense SIFT is simply SIFT features computed on a grid at different scale.

Comment: Implementation of DenseFeatureDetector detectImpl was like this. I guess you can do this on your own, but I guess I cannot help you more as I am no mathematician nor CV expert. https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/features2d/src/detectors.cpp#L162

Comment: Thanks @DawidPi. I did a search for "Dense" in the opencv_contrib as well as in /features2d but looks like the function has been dropped. Looks like I have to implement it myself as you suggest.

Comment: DenseFeatureDetector was remved in OpenCV 3.0 http://answers.opencv.org/question/61225/dense-features-in-opencv-3/

Comment: You can use alternative of SIFT like BRISK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I used dense SIFT in OpenCV 3 C++:

```
SiftDescriptorExtractor sift;

vector<KeyPoint> keypoints; // keypoint storage
Mat descriptors; // descriptor storage

// manual keypoint grid

int step = 10; // 10 pixels spacing between kp's

for (int y=step; y<img.rows-step; y+=step){
    for (int x=step; x<img.cols-step; x+=step){

        // x,y,radius
        keypoints.push_back(KeyPoint(float(x), float(y), float(step)));
    }
}

// compute descriptors

sift.compute(img, keypoints, descriptors);
```

copied from:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/73165/compute-dense-sift-features-in-opencv-30/?answer=73178#post-id-73178

seems to work well

Comment: If I want to extract features from several images...
Should I resize all images to a common size first?

Comment: Thanks a lot. (And sorry for the delay)

Answer (score 17):

You can pass a list of `cv2.KeyPoints` to `sift.compute`. This example is in Python, but it shows the principle. I create a list of `cv2.KeyPoint`s by scanning through the pixel locations of the image:

```
import skimage.data as skid
import cv2
import pylab as plt

img = skid.lena()
gray= cv2.cvtColor(img ,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

step_size = 5
kp = [cv2.KeyPoint(x, y, step_size) for y in range(0, gray.shape[0], step_size) 
                                    for x in range(0, gray.shape[1], step_size)]

img=cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp, img)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

dense_feat = sift.compute(gray, kp)
```

Comment: Hi, do you know how to apply contrast threshold in this case? I tried to add contrastThreshold parameter in SIFT_create() but it was ignored.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but it looks like as you would have to implement it yourself. The answer is complicated enough to post it as a separate question. However, the contrast seems to be calculated here https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/7238cd27bae5436605d9e32ca0b87f266381a9e0/modules/xfeatures2d/src/sift.cpp#L457